# can someone tell me what's wrong with my algebra for solving matrix equation

Tags: matrices

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEC7q.png)

$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$ * $\begin{bmatrix}-10 & 0\\2 & 4\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}20 & 0\\0 & 20\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$ * $\begin{bmatrix}-10 & 0\\2 & 4\end{bmatrix}$ = 20 * $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$ * $\begin{bmatrix}-10 & 0\\2 & 4\end{bmatrix}$ *1/20 = $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$ * $\begin{bmatrix}-0.5 & 0\\0.1 & 0.2\end{bmatrix}$  = $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

and using the inverse formula we can say that

a =0.2, b = -0.1, c = 0, d =-0.5

where am I wrong?

p.s: I know that I can just multiply them to find the answer, this is more just to see what in my logic about matrices is wrong because this seems like a thing you should be able to do.

Comment: Don't forget when you invert the matrix that way, you need to divide by its determinant.  Also $ \ b \ $ and $ \ c \ $ only change sign; they _don't_ swap places.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{pmatrix}-10&0\\2&4\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{-40}\begin{pmatrix}4&0\\-2&-10\end{pmatrix}$ since $-40=\det\begin{pmatrix}-10&0\\2&4\end{pmatrix}$

Now right-multiply both sides of the equation by $\begin{pmatrix}-10&0\\2&4\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$ to obtain
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}=\dfrac{1}{-40}\begin{pmatrix}20&0\\0&20\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}4&0\\-2&-10\end{pmatrix}=-\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\-1&-5\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-2&0\\1&5\end{pmatrix}$$
where I have taken a factor of $1/20$ into the first matrix and a factor of $1/2$ into the second matrix.